# Creating forest mask using PALSAR Forest/Non-Forest Map for Sentinel 2 image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, masking, forest-ecology

I trying mask forest areas in Sentinel- 2 image collection over my study area using the 25m resolution global PALSAR Forest/Non-Forest Map. I followed the masking example given in GEE guides that uses Hansen et al. forest change dataset. It shows fnf.eq is not a function as an error when I am defining the mask layer. The code is attached below. How can I solve the problem?

```
var geometry:https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/monish_d/MP
var s2= ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR").filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10));
var vis = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 2000, gamma: 1.5};
var area = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry); var opacity = 0.5; Map.centerObject(area, 6.5);
var ImCol = ee.ImageCollection(s2.filterDate('2020-02-15','2020-02-28') //// Filter by dates.
.filterBounds(area)); 
//// Creat a Cloud Mask.
function maskS2sr(image) {
 var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int(); ////cloud band
 var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();//// cirrus band
 var qa = image.select('QA60'); //// Get the pixel QA band.
var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)  ////  Flags set to zero for clear conditions.
.and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0)); ////  Flags set to zero for clear conditions. return image.updateMask(mask) //// Return the masked image, scaled to TOA reflectance, without the QA bands.
  .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);}
//// Apply cloud mask to image collections
var CM_ImCol = ImCol.map(maskS2sr);
////creat forest mask
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR/YEARLY/FNF')
              .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31'); ////global 25m resolution PALSAR-2/PALSAR SAR mosaic
var fnf = dataset.select('fnf');
var Fmask = fnf.eq(1); ////1:forest, 2:nonforest, 3:water
////Define forest Mask function
var maskforest = function(image) {return image.updateMask(image.select(Fmask));};
/////Apply forest mask to image collections
var CFM_ImCol = CM_ImCol.map(maskforest);
////Mosaic and clip images
var mos = CFM_ImCol.median().clip(area);
Map.addLayer(mos, vis,'Masked image');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataset` is a collection, not an image, so you can't do image-like things with it.  Get the first result (which will be an image) with `first()`.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('JAXA/ALOS/PALSAR/YEARLY/FNF')
              .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
              .first()
```

Comment: Dear Noel thanks for your help but I'm getting new error: Masked image: Layer error: Image.select, argument 'bandSelectors': Invalid type.
Expected type: List<Object>.
Actual type: Image<[fnf]>.    I tried printing the image it shows 1 band with ID: fnf. I'm confused, what is mean by invalid type?. I can even add the image to the map. Its fine with all the original attributes still the error is there.

Comment: Can you add a link to the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I detected my mistake. It was a in  my script itself. I was giving the wrong source for the band. But thanks a lot for your help.